# Is this crack just drywall problem or foundation?

Tags: foundation

I bought my house about 9 months ago. I'm just now noticing what looks like a horizontal crack patched up. This is next to my window.

Am I looking at that correctly... Was there a crack and the original owner tried to cover it? Does this mean that I have foundation issues? Or is the drywall just acting up?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt very much that it's a foundation problem or anything serious. Little cracks like that, especially around windows are pretty common. Holes in block are made for the windows and then framed with wood and the windows are then shimmed in place. Then drywalled so lots of settling. Plus people are alays hanging drapes and blinds so the drywall gets beat up pretty bad and then repairs are made.

Answer (score 2):

Minor cracks, especially horizontal or vertical ones, are generally just random effects of age, and harmless. Patch 'em, preferably with mesh tape for strength, and don't worry.

Long (and growing) cracks, especially diagonal cracks in old lath-and-plaster, may indicate foundation settling occurred in the past and the plaster wasn't properly patched after that was stopped... or settling is occurring now. The latter would be a concern, so at would be worth keeping an eye on.

Comment: Which kind of crack would you classify this one as?

Comment: Keep an eye on it for 5 years & you'll know ;)

Comment: "Don't worry about it yet." Go ahead and patch it. If it opens again and goes farther, then you can start being suspicious.

Comment: That crack would be classified as Superficial.